# Categories & Tags created with the REST API returning 404 when viewed

Tags: rest-api, 404-error

I have software that pushes content to my WordPress website using the REST API. Part of the process creates tags and categories for the content if they don't exist already, and retrieves the IDs of the categories and tags which is then pushed to the website.

What I'm now finding is that these categories and tags that are created through the REST API return 404 errors when being viewed on the front end. Categories that I've added manually through the dashboard don't return 404s. It's just the REST API created ones.

The code I use for the REST API is here, which in turn provides an ID which I pass on to the request that posts the content to the site:

```
        $newCategory = array(
            'name' => 'category name'
        );

        $ch = curl_init($protocol.'://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($newCategory));

        $serverOutput = curl_exec($ch);
```

In terms of how the site is set up, the permalinks are set to use `category` and `tag` respective for the URL base.

I'm not aware of anything missing from the creation of the category using the API, so I'm a bit perplexed as to why using the REST API it returns a 404 but adding them manually doesn't.

Edit #1: I've reset the permalinks (again) and it doesn't improve the situation. I've also used two of the standard WordPress themes (Twenty Ninteen and Twenty Twenty-Two) and they both return 404's as well.